# Can't format datetime in carbon

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

When I try to format my `$date` to `d/m/Y` it's work fine

```
$date = '20/4/2015';
Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date)
```

But when I try to format my `$date` to `d/M/Y`

```
$date = '20/4/2015';
Carbon::createFromFormat('d/M/Y', $date)
```

I got an error like the following,

> The separation symbol could not be found Trailing data

What does wrong in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

M means textual representation of month. 4 cannot be parset into month and it fails even though with strange message. Try this and it works

```
    $date = '20/Jan/2015';
    $carbDate=Carbon::createFromFormat('d/M/Y', $date);
    dd($carbDate);
```

Outputs

```
Carbon {#260 ▼
  +"date": "2015-01-20 10:01:01"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "UTC"
}
```